# Access View as Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I am trying to access one of my edit views as a modal in my application. I have my Show.html in readings as shown here

```
<%- model_class = Reading -%>
<div class="page-header">
<h1><%=t '.title', :default => model_class.model_name.human %></h1>
 </div>

<dl class="dl-horizontal">
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:customer_id) %>:</strong></dt>
    <dd><%= @reading.customer_id %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:date_of_reading) %>:</strong></dt>
    <dd><%= @reading.date_of_reading %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:reading1) %>:</strong></dt>
    <dd><%= @reading.reading1 %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:reading2) %>:</strong></dt>
    <dd><%= @reading.reading2 %></dd>
  <dt><strong><%= model_class.human_attribute_name(:reading3) %>:</strong></dt>
    <dd><%= @reading.reading3 %></dd>
</dl>

<div class="form-actions">
   <%= link_to t('.back', :default => t("helpers.links.back")),
          customer_readings_path, :class => 'btn'  %>
   <%= link_to t('.edit', :default => t("helpers.links.edit")),
          edit_customer_reading_path(@reading.customer, @reading), :class => 'btn', :data => {:toggle => "modal", :target => "#editItemModal"} %>
   <%= link_to t('.destroy', :default => t("helpers.links.destroy")),
          customer_reading_path(@reading.customer),
          :method => 'delete',
          :data => { :confirm => t('.confirm', :default => t("helpers.links.confirm",  :default => 'Are you sure?')) },
          :class => 'btn btn-danger' %>
</div>
```

In my edit View, readings/edit

```
<div id= "editItemModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button></h1>
<div class = "page-header">
<h1> Editing Readings </h1>
</div>

<%= render 'form_reading'%>
</div>
```

However, on clicking edit in my show, the edit view does not show up as a modal, it just shows a blank page. What can i be missing?

Comment: In the server log, does the edit action actually get called and then completes without any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

1) First you need to ajaxify the edit link by adding `:remote => true`.

2)This div needs to be on show page.(Only the div and not the content inside it.)

```
<div id= "editItemModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

</div>
```

3) Make `edit.html.erb` a partial by changing its name to `_edit.html.erb`

4) Add this javascript code on show page

```
$('#link_id').on('ajax:success', function(e, data){
  $('#editItemModal').html(data);
});
```

5)In your controller edit action write this `render 'edit', :layout => false`

There might be some spelling mistakes or small bugs in this code. But I've have used it many times. So i'll suggest you to try this.